# Snap vertex to edge in only one direction

Tags: vertices, edges, snapping

I'm trying to snap a vertex to the edge right above with with axis locked to z. But it just slides along the edge. Going to vertex mode doesn't help either. This should be possible though as there is only one solution for blender to accomplish this really... idk if this could be a feature request? It's not the first time I'm encountering this problem.

[image]

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Would you like workarounds as answers?  For example, use knife with angle constrain, cut a new vertex where you need to snap to, snap to that vertex, remove it after.  Alternatively, use one of the many addons (TinyCad is good) to construct or modify the mesh to have a vertex there quicker, but either way they're not really direct solutions.

Comment: I tried tinyCAD, it just creates a vertex in the open, but I need it to be part of the face.